# How to customize status bar icons and text color? E.g. status bar background: white, status bar icon color, and text: red

Tags: android, xamarin.android, icons, statusbar

[android][android studio][status bar]

I cannot find how to change colors of statusbar in andriod using xml.

[1]This is the photo of example how it must look -->: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0QM4.png

Comment: You can change statusbar color within your app however you like, however android only supports black or white icons & text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,android only supports black or white icons & text.

We can change the statusBarColor of status bar by property `android:statusBarColor` in file `styles.xml`:

```
 <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorgreen</item>
```

And when we change the value of property `android:windowLightStatusBar` to `true`,the color of  icons & text will be grayed out.

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

When using the following code:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!-- other code -->
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorgreen</item>
  <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

The result is:

[image]