# How to Change Status Bar Background, Text Color for Single Content Page Xamarin (Ios, Android)

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to Change Status Bar Background, Text Color for Single Content Page.

I add:

styles.xml

[image]

I think it works on all Content Pages

[image]

I want:

Page1: Status Bar Background is Green.

Page2: Status Bar Background is Red.
...

Thank you!

Comment: A similar question has been answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993741/xamarin-forms-change-statusbar-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to Change Status Bar Background, Text Color for Single Content
> Page Xamarin (Ios, Android)

If you want to change the Status Bar Background color for single page, you can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to achieve this.

1.In xamarin forms,add interface `IStatusBarPlatformSpecific`

```
public interface IStatusBarPlatformSpecific
{
    void SetStatusBarColor(Color color);
}
```

2.In android,add class `ChangeStatusbar` to implement interface `IStatusBarPlatformSpecific`:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ChangeStatusbar))]
namespace ToastApp.Droid
{
    public class ChangeStatusbar : IStatusBarPlatformSpecific
    {
        public ChangeStatusbar()
        {
        }

        public void SetStatusBarColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
        {
            // The SetStatusBarcolor is new since API 21
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                var androidColor = color.AddLuminosity(-0.1).ToAndroid();
                //Just use the plugin
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity.Window.SetStatusBarColor(androidColor);
            }
            else
            {
                // Here you will just have to set your 
                // color in styles.xml file as shown below.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note:Android only supports black or white icons & text.

For more, check:[How to customize status bar icons and text color? E.g. status bar background: white, status bar icon color, and text: red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68309268/how-to-customize-status-bar-icons-and-text-color-e-g-status-bar-background-wh/68310655#68310655)

3.In IOS,create class `ChangeStatusbarIOS` to implement interface `IStatusBarPlatformSpecific`:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ChangeStatusbarIOS))]
namespace ToastApp.iOS
{
    public class ChangeStatusbarIOS : IStatusBarPlatformSpecific
    {
        public void SetStatusBarColor(Color color)
        {

            UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
            //statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;

            statusBar.BackgroundColor = color.AddLuminosity(-0.1).ToUIColor();
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
        }
    }
}
```

4.In forms, you can change status backbround color for Single Content Page by override method `OnAppearing` and change back to it's original color by override method `OnDisappearing`:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var statusbar = DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarPlatformSpecific>();
        statusbar.SetStatusBarColor(Color.Green);
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        var statusbar = DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarPlatformSpecific>();
        statusbar.SetStatusBarColor(Color.FromHex("3F51B5"));
    }
```

Comment: On Android it works fine, but on IOS it gives an error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

on ios:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ChangeStatusbarIOS))]
namespace ToastApp.iOS
{
    public class ChangeStatusbarIOS : IStatusBarPlatformSpecific
    {
        public void SetStatusBarColor(Color color)
        {

            UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
            //statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;

            statusBar.BackgroundColor = color.AddLuminosity(-0.1).ToUIColor();
            //UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);

                foreach (UIScene scene in UIApplication.SharedApplication.ConnectedScenes)
            {
                if (scene.ActivationState == UISceneActivationState.ForegroundActive)
                {
                    UIWindowScene myScene = (UIWindowScene)scene;
                    foreach (UIWindow win in myScene.Windows)
                    {
                        if (win.IsKeyWindow)
                        {
                            win.AddSubview(statusBar);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```